# django registration custom send activation email

Tags: django, email, registration, activation

Can anyone try to overide send_activation_email method?I need to send two different activation email, and in one of them I need to put some extra data (as login, etc.). I see this method in RegistrationProfile class, but this method is calling by creative_inactive_user method which I call in backend.

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more detail? Why can't you override that exact method to do whatever you wish? It sounds like you're saying `create_inactive_user` has something to do with this, but how is it a problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it much easier on yourself, check out [this Django plugin](https://github.com/vvarp/django-postageapp) that someone wrote for PostageApp.

In [PostageApp](http://www.postageapp.com/), you can take care of the different emails by using templates; one parent template with your overall design, and two child templates that contains whatever information that might be necessary. For example, one of your child templates can contain the login information, and the other can have whatever else you might want to include.

I understand if you would want to learn how to do this yourself in Django, but I am just making sure you know of the much easier alternative.

Cheers!

(**Full Disclosure**: I am the Product Manager for PostageApp)

Comment: No problem, I hope it makes your life easier. Cheers!